# Torque job logging configuration file

Tags: logging, configuration, jobs, pbs, torque

I'm using PBS Torque and I have it in a production setting but I just realized that /var/spool/torque/job_logs is empty, I just checked the manual and it reads:

There are five new server parameters used to enable job logging. These parameters control what information is stored in the log and manage the log files.

(Manual section on job logging is here: http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-4/help.htm#topics/10-logging/enablingJobLogs.htm)

But the manual doesn't specify where these parameters can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the manual could be slightly clearer. These parameters are set via qmgr because they are server parameters. For example:

```
qmgr -c 'set server record_job_info = true'
```

All of these parameters can be set in a similar fashion.

Comment: Great! it's exactly what I needed, I'm just gonna start doing that, thank you very much!